# Sharing dataconnection between objects

Tags: delphi, ado, vcl

I am trying to create a small app where you can save districts, stores and employees to a database. Right now I create a new `TAdoConnection` in all of my classes constructors (`TDistrict.Create`, `TEmployee.Create` etc.)and execute a query. But there has to be another way. I thought about creating the `TAdoConnection` at a higher level and pass it to the constructors as parameters, but I also don't that is the correct way. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they live in the same thread this is the way to go. You could create a data module and hold your global connection object there.

Comment: My application is very simple and single threaded - what would be the right way to store a connection in the data module(which i have never heard of)

Comment: A Data Module is the way to go here. Would you like us to find and post its documentation for you?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will help u:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TController = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FConnecteur: TAdoConnection;
    procedure SetConnecteur(const Value: TAdoConnection);
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Connecteur: TAdoConnection read FConnecteur write SetConnecteur;
  end;

  TDistrict = class(TController)

  public
    constructor Create(AConnection: TAdoConnection);
  end;

(*the same think with TEmployee and other class*)

implementation

constructor TController.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  //Self.FConnecteur:= TAdoConnection.Create(); {if u want to create single connection *1}
end;

destructor TController.Destroy;
begin
  //Self.FConnecteur.free; (*1 if single connection was created *)
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TController.SetConnecteur(const Value: TAdoConnection);
begin
  FConnecteur := Value;
end;

constructor TDistrict.Create(AConnection: TAdoConnection);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Self.FConnecteur:= AConnection;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Not sure I understand it - I will still have to create a new instance of a TAdoConnection for every object I want to instantiate?

Comment: if u want  to create for every instance, yes, else you can use the properties Connecteur for Parent (inherited from TController).

Comment: As far as I can tell, you would still need to provide a new instance of TAdoConnection property? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This will not work. The parent is a class... not an object. Declaring a property in the parent class does not, in any way, make that property shared among all instances of subclasses.

Comment: @Matt Baech, look at TDistrict.Create(AConnection: TAdoConnection); the AConnection is shared between TDistrict instance, and all other object u want to create, juste create one instance of AConnection and pass it as parameter to TDistrict, TEmployee, ..